# Odd behavior noticed during UI tests with Selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#, uiautomation

I want to ask you about the odd behavior I noticed when running multiple tests, using Visual studio, Selenium web-driver and Chrome browser.

I have all the tests written as follows:

1. sign in to the web app
2. go to desired page
3. take action on this page
4. sign out of the web app

In the older version of the browser and web-driver I started multiple tests,
if one of the tests failed on the desired page (test was logged in app),
after the time has passed then test was terminated and web app has been automatically redirected to the login page.
Another test, in order, could be logged in and continued.

But now, with the current version of the browser and web-driver,
if one of the tests failed on the desired page, the test will remain logged in the app, and another test cannot be signed in, because the web app was not redirected to the login page.

Have you noticed the same behavior?
What can I do about it, how to fix it?

Thank you in advance for your ideas and assistance.

- Chrome 78.0.3904.108
- Selenium WebDriver 3.141.0
- ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.105

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were not explicitly quitting the driver before and you are not doing that now as well then the change could be because of the change in below two areas

> Probably something in the logic of how you start/quit your driver and/or tests.
>   Probably the change could be in the behavior of the application being tested.

In my experience the issue you are describing isn't related to the version of driver you are using but more so from the two areas listed above.

Comment: Resolved: the "webAppUrl" parameter did not contain the correct URL to login page, in the runsettings file.